# How do I refer to a class with multiple template types by only one of the types?

Tags: c++, c++17

Let's say I have a class `Shape` with the declaration:

```
template <typename T, typename U, typename V>
class Shape {
   T value;
   U input;
   V input2;

   ...
}
```

As it is, if I create a `Shape` object, its type will be something like `Shape<int, float, double>` - for example.

But what if I want to be able to create a `Shape` object and still give it inputs of different types (like `float` and `double`), but I want its type to be `Shape<int>`.

That is, after creating a `Shape` object, I want callers to only care about the type of its value, not the type of its inputs. How do you suggest I go about it?

I've learned that I cannot store templates member variables without having declared the template types at the top. I've also attempted using an alias like:

```
template <typename T, typename U, typename V>
using ShapeAlias<T> = Shape<T, U, V>
```

But that doesn't work either. Do you have any suggestions on how I can go about this?

I'm considering some form of inheritance where there's a base class with only one of the types, and the derived class contains all three types, but I thought I should check here.

Edit: I need the second and third types because the idea is that a user will be able to pass a function to a `Shape` constructor to calculate the value of T, which could look like:

```
auto creator = [](U a, V b){
   return (something of type T)
}
```

And I want to keep the values of the input types in the `Shape` class.

So from a client's perspective, their code should look like this:

```
Shape<T> shapeA(Shape<T>(uValue, vValue, creator)
```

As it is now, they would have to do:

```
Shape<T, U, V> shapeA(Shape<T, U, V>(uValue, vValue, creator))
```

Comment: Not sure I understand. But anyway template instansiation is done at compile time. So I don't think you'll be able to create a Shape<int> object that will be able to accept all kinds of inputs (assuming those inputs are template arguments as in your code).

Comment: If you only want the user to care about the one member variable, why did you add more public member variables. Regardless of you using a type alias or not, a change in `U` and `V` does mean that the data structure `Shape` is different. You may be able to apply some tricks to ignore this difference, but to recommend something, we need to know about the purpose of keeping the 2 fields of type `U` and `V` in the struct in the first place... Perhaps adding a code snippet showing the desired use could be added?

Comment: A [mre] is needed to elaborate on what user should care and why you need the second and third types.

Comment: You cannot have members of type `U` and `V` if the type should be independent of `U` and `V`. The solution seems to be to not store `U` and `V` as members

Comment: what do you want `U` and `V` to be when the user is instantiating `Shape<float>` ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I don't want the class to be independent of `U` and `V`.  

`U` and `V` can be of any type as long as the function the user passes returns a type `float`.

Comment: but you cannot have members of "any type" (unless its `std::any` but I dont think you want that).

Comment: You contradict yourself. _" I want callers to only care about the type of its value"_ but the caller also needs to know the type of the callback.

Comment: is there an unambiguous mapping from `T` to `U` and `V` ? I mean when T is eg `int` do you know that `U` and `V` are always `float` and `double` ?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Metaprogramming may or may not answer the question in letter, but most likely not in spirit. There's a fundamental misconception somewhere here.

Comment: it is still uclear whehter caller specifies `T` or `U` and `V`. In your example `Shape<T> shapeA(Shape<T>(uValue, vValue, creator)` the caller needs to know all three

Comment: I think I understand the confusion. The caller will certainly know the types of U and V given that they're creating the object. 

What I want to achieve is that `U` and `V` don't then reflect in the object type. So that if I want to create a function that accepts a `Shape`, for example, it can accept a type `Shape<T>` and not `Shape<T, U, V>`.  My goal is just to make things look a bit cleaner.

Comment: but if you have members of type `U` and `V` then `U` and `V` do reflect in the type. If `U` and `V` are  different then its a different type of `Shape`. What you can do is that the caller only explicitly specifies `T` while `U` and `V` are deduced (see answer).

Comment: you can make  `Shape` depend on `T` only when there is a unique mapping from `T` to `U` and `V`. But if you want members of type `U` and `V` then there is no way around speficifing `U` and `V` somehow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for CTAD (class template argument deduction). It only works when the caller does not specify any template argument, hence a layer of indirection has to be added:

```
template <typename T>
struct ShapeWrap {
    template <typename U,typename V>
    struct Shape {
        T value;
        U input;
        V input2;
        Shape(const U& u,const V& v) : input(u),input2(v) {}
    };
};
```

Caller can now call:

```
auto s = ShapeWrap<int>::Shape(1.0,0.1f);
```

To instantiate `ShapeWrap<int>::Shape<double,float>`.

---

Alternatively via template argument deduction of a function template:

```
template <typename T, typename U,typename V>
struct Shape {
    T value;
    U input;
    V input2;
    Shape(const U& u,const V& v) : input(u),input2(v) {}
};

template <typename T,typename U,typename V>
Shape<T,U,V> make_shape(const U& u, const V& v) {
    return {u,v};
}



int main() {
    auto s = make_shape<int>(1.0,0.1f);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in this direction. I ended up doing something similar, where `Shape` inherits from `ShapeWrap` instead of being nested.  This way, I can call `Shape<T, U, V>` functions through `ShapeWrap<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

If the creator object is only used in the constructor itself, but you don't need to store the values for later use, you could just resort to a templated constructor. If you do need to store the value the full type including all type parameters need to be specified, if the user has to name the type themselves. You could design the class in a way for `auto` to be useable.

**Alternative 1: Create a function for creating the object.**

This allows the user to specify some of the template parameters starting from the left, but having the rest deduced by the compiler.

```
template<class Product, class CreatorType, class ...Args>
class Factory
{
public:
    Factory(CreatorType const& creator, Args...args)
        : m_creator(creator), m_arguments(args...)
    {
    }

    Product Create()
    {
        return std::apply(m_creator, m_arguments);
    }
private:
    CreatorType m_creator;
    std::tuple<Args...> m_arguments;
};

template<class Product, class CreatorType, class ...Args>
auto CreateFactory(CreatorType const& creator, Args ... args)
{
    return Factory<Product, CreatorType, Args...>(creator, args...);
}

int main() {

    auto creator = [](int value) -> int { return value + 1; };

    auto factory = CreateFactory<long>(creator, 41); // we're able do add a type conversion int -> long here

    std::cout << "The answer is " << factory.Create() << '\n';
}
```

**Alternative 2: Add a class template argument deduction (CTAD) guideline**

If you're ok with having the return type automatically be deduced based on the result of invoking the creator, you could create a CTAD guideline automatically deducing the type parameters, if the user does not specify any of the template parameters.

```
template<class Product, class CreatorType, class ...Args>
class Factory
{
public:

    Factory(CreatorType const& creator, Args const&...args)
        : m_creator(creator), m_arguments(args...)
    {
    }

    Product Create()
    {
        return std::apply(m_creator, m_arguments);
    }
private:
    CreatorType m_creator;
    std::tuple<Args...> m_arguments;
};

// deduction guideline: the result of calling creator with the arguments is used as the first template parameter
template<class CreatorType, class ... Args>
Factory(CreatorType const&, Args const&...) -> Factory<decltype(std::apply(std::declval<CreatorType>(), std::declval<std::tuple<Args...>>())), CreatorType, Args...>;

int main() {
    auto creator = [](int value) -> int { return value + 1; };

    Factory factory(creator, 41); // type of factory automatically chosen to be Factory<int, ..., int>

    std::cout << "The answer is " << factory.Create() << '\n';
}
```